# Why is the average noise generated by the two-sided geometric distribution not null?

Tags: probability, distributions, noise

I am implementing the distributed differential privacy scheme proposed in this paper http://www.elaineshi.com/docs/ndss2011.pdf. Page 13 they represent a graph with the error added by a naive scheme and they say that "the naive scheme is where each participant adds independent geometric noise to her input and uploads the perturbed data to the aggregator". The geometric distribution proposed in this paper to generate noise is the two-sided geometric distribution whose probability mass function at k is (α−1/α+1)·α^(−|k|) where α > 1. It looks like this, with α=1.1 [image]

I don't understand why the error increases (for the naive scheme) with the number of users, since the mean of the probability distribution is 0. It seems to me that if we have N users adding independent noise to their data with this probability distribution, the ones adding negative noise and the ones adding positive noise should compensate, and when the aggregator does the sum of their data we should get an error close to 0. I am probably missing something...

Thank you all :)

Answer (score 2):

The plot on page 13 shows the mean and standard deviation of error *in absolute terms*. Since they're using the absolute value of errors, positive and negative errors do not cancel out. Since they're looking at error over a summation problem, the more items they sum, the bigger the error gets.

Comment: I thought the error in absolute value meant | ∑ Ri | (where Ri is the noise added to the value Xi) and not ∑ | Ri | since the error of the scheme is defined as ∑ Ẍi - ∑ Xi (where Ẍi = Xi + Ri). Indeed in this case your answer would make sense but I am not sure which one of the two terms they are plotting. Thanks for the answer.